# Using Google Maps InfoBox for Points Stored in an Array

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have used InfoBox successfully in a fairly simple application but I am struggling to make it work on something just slightly more complex. For sure I am missing something simple.

The aim is to show a map with a hotel and the nearest airport(s). Then the InfoBox shows the name of the hotel (very simple: no problem) and a list of flights that serve the airport (the problem!). The hotel details are passed as parameters in the URL. The airport details are an array stored in the script.

The problem I have is that when I click the airport icon, the map jumps to the last airport in the airport array and displays the InfoBox contents for that last airport.

You can see the problem at http://http://new.littlehotels.co.uk/maps/map_airport_spain.php?lat=39.755688&lng=2.636354&zoom=9&hotel=Hotel%20Colorado.

The code is:

```
<?php 
$hotel = $_GET['hotel'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Little Hotels - Google Map</title>
<meta name="description" content="Little Hotels provides maps showing the location of hotels, using Google Maps to create both a street/road map and a satellite image.">
<meta name="keywords" content="Little Hotels, Little Hotels of Spain, Spain, Little Hotels of Morocco, Morocco, Little Hotels of France, France, mainland spain, balearic, balearics, canary, canaries, small, hotel, hotels, map, google map, holiday, holidays">
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body{ height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#333333;}
a:link, a:visited, a:hover {color: #FF6600; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold;}
h1{font-size: 16px; color: #2B8CB9; font-weight: bold;}
#content{padding: 0 5px 0; width: 640px;}
#map_canvas { height: 100%; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; color:#4d6eb0;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/infobox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/downloadxml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
     // global "map" variable
      var map = null;

  var hotelimage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../images/hotel_icon.gif',
      new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(16, 35));
  var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../images/hotel_shadow.png',
      new google.maps.Size(51, 37),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(16, 35));

// A function to create the markers and set up the event window function 
function createMarker(latlng, hotel) {
    var contentString = hotel;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng,
        icon: image,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        var ib = new InfoBox(ibOptions);
        boxText.innerHTML = contentString;
        ib.open(map, marker);
        });
}

// This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}

// InfoBox
 var boxText = document.createElement("div");
        boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid #4d6eb0; margin-top: 8px; background: white; padding: 5px;";

        var ibOptions = {
                 content: boxText
                ,disableAutoPan: false
                ,maxWidth: 0
                ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(10, -50)
                ,zIndex: null
                ,boxStyle: { 
                  width: "160px"
                 }
                ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
                ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
                ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
                ,isHidden: false
                ,pane: "floatPane"
                ,enableEventPropagation: false
        };
////////////////////////7

function initialize() {
      var lat = 0;
      var lng = 0;
      var zoom = 0;
      var hotelname = 0;
      var query = location.search.substring(1);
      var pairs = query.split("&");
      for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {
    var pos = pairs[i].indexOf("=");
    var argname = pairs[i].substring(0,pos).toLowerCase();
    var value = pairs[i].substring(pos+1);
        if (argname == "lat") {lat = parseFloat(value);}
        if (argname == "lng") {lng = parseFloat(value);}
        if (argname == "zoom") {zoom = parseInt(value);}
        if (argname == "hotel") {hotelname = unescape(value);}
      }
    var thisLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  var myOptions = {
center: thisLatlng,
zoom: zoom,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
   streetViewControl: false,
   zoomControl: true,
   zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
   }
   }

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);

  setMarkers(map, airports);


//////////////////////
  var hotelmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: thisLatlng,
      map: map,
      icon: hotelimage,
      shadow: shadow,
      zIndex: 9999
  });
      google.maps.event.addListener(hotelmarker, 'click', function() {
        var ib = new InfoBox(ibOptions);
        boxText.innerHTML = hotelname;
        ib.open(map, hotelmarker);
        });

////////////////////


  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        });

}

var airports = [
// This section was common to airport_float.php and flights.php, may still go with flights.php
[38.287242,-0.557299,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Alicante airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="135">Belfast </td><td>Aer Lingus, EasyJet, Flybe, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Birmingham </td><td>bmibaby, Monarch, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Blackpool </td><td>Jet2 </td></tr><tr><td>Bournemouth </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Bristol </td><td>EasyJet, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Cardiff </td><td>bmibaby, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Cork </td><td>Aer Lingus </td></tr><tr><td>Doncaster Sheffield </td><td>Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Dublin </td><td>Aer Lingus, Flybe, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Durham Tees Valley </td><td>Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>East Midlands </td><td>bmibaby, Jet2, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Edinburgh </td><td>EasyJet, Flybe, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Exeter </td><td>Flybe </td></tr><tr><td>Glasgow </td><td>EasyJet, Flybe, Jet2, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Guernsey </td><td>Flybe </td></tr><tr><td>Isle of Man </td><td>Flybe </td></tr><tr><td>Jersey </td><td>Flybe </td></tr><tr><td>Kerry </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Knock </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Leeds Bradford </td><td>Jet2, Flybe, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Liverpool </td><td>EasyJet, Ryanair, </td></tr><tr><td>London Gatwick </td><td>EasyJet, Monarch, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>London Luton </td><td>EasyJet, Monarch </td></tr><tr><td>London Stansted </td><td>airberlin, EasyJet, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Manchester </td><td>EasyJet, Flybe, Jet2, Monarch, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Newcastle </td><td>EasyJet, Flybe, Jet2, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Newquay </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Norwich </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Southampton </td><td>Flybe </td></tr></table>'],
[36.848101,-2.371502,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Almeria airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">Birmingham </td><td>Monarch </td></tr><tr><td>East Midlands </td><td>bmibaby </td></tr><tr><td>London Gatwick </td><td>EasyJet </td></tr><tr><td>London Stansted </td><td>Ryan Air </td></tr><tr><td>Manchester </td><td>Monarch </td></tr></table>'],
[43.559434,-6.032181,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Asturias (Oviedo) airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">Stansted</td><td>EasyJet</td></tr></table>'],
[41.29896,2.076931,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Barcelona airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">Belfast </td><td>Aer Lingus, EasyJet </td></tr><tr><td>Bristol </td<td>EasyJet </td></tr><tr><td>Cork </td><td>Aer Lingus </td></tr><tr><td>Doncaster Sheffield </td><td>EasyJet </td></tr><tr><td>Dublin </td><td>Aer Lingus, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>East Midlands </td><td>bmibaby </td></tr><tr><td>Edinburgh </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Leeds Bradford </td><td>Jet2, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Liverpool </td><td>EasyJet </td></tr><tr><td>London City </td><td>BA Cityflyer </td></tr><tr><td>London Gatwick </td><td>EasyJet </td></tr><tr><td>London Heathrow </td><td>British Airways </td></tr><tr><td>London Luton </td><td>EasyJet </td></tr><tr><td>London Stansted </td><td>airberlin, EasyJet </td></tr><tr><td>Manchester </td><td>Monarch </td></tr><tr><td>Newcastle </td><td>EasyJet </td></tr></table>'],
[43.305194,-2.906055,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Bilbao airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">Dublin </td><td>Aer Lingus </td></tr><tr><td>London Heathrow </td><td>Vueling </td></tr><tr><td>London Stansted </td><td>EasyJet </td></tr></table>'],
[36.152638,-5.348368,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Gibraltar airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">London Gatwick </td><td>EasyJet </td></tr><tr><td>London Heathrow </td><td>British Airways </td></tr><tr><td>Liverpool </td><td>EasyJet </td></tr><tr><td>London Luton </td><td>Monarch </td></tr><tr><td>Manchester </td><td>Monarch </td></tr></table>'],
[41.898827,2.765465,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Girona airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">Birmingham </td><td>Ryanair,Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Bournemouth </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Bristol </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Dublin </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>East Midlands </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Glasgow </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Liverpool </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>London Gatwick </td><td>Ryanair,Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>London Luton </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>London Stansted </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Manchester </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Newcastle </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr></table>'],
[37.185963,-3.776894,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Granada airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td>No flights from UK or Ireland at the moment</td></tr></table>'],
[38.876334,1.367626,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Ibiza airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">Aberdeen </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td width="130">Belfast </td><td>EasyJet, Jet2, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Birmingham </td><td>Monarch, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Bournemouth </td><td>Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Bristol </td><td>EasyJet, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Cardiff </td><td>Bmibaby, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Doncaster Sheffield </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Dublin </td><td>Aer Lingus, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>East Midlands </td><td>Bmibaby, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Edinburgh </td><td>Jet2, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Exeter </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Glasgow </td><td>EasyJet, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Leeds Bradford </td><td>Jet2, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Liverpool </td><td>EasyJet, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>London Gatwick </td><td>EasyJet, Monarch, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>London Luton </td><td>EasyJet, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>London Stansted </td><td>EasyJet, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Manchester </td><td>Jet2, Monarch, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Newcastle </td><td>EasyJet, Jet2, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Norwich </td><td>Thomson </td></tr></table>'],
[36.750164,-6.06411,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Jerez airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">London Stansted</td><td>Ryanair</td></tr></table>'],
[43.302071,-8.380938,'<b><u>Flights Guide - La Coruña airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">London Heathrow</td><td>Vueling</td></tr></table>'],
[40.46889,-3.56884,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Madrid airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">Bristol </td><td>EasyJet </td></tr><tr><td>Dublin </td><td>Aer Lingus, Ryan Air </td></tr><tr><td>Edinburgh </td><td>EasyJet </td></tr><tr><td>Liverpool </td><td>EasyJet </td></tr><tr><td>London City </td><td>BA Cityflyer </td></tr><tr><td>London Gatwick </td><td>EasyJet, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>London Heathrow </td><td>British Airways, Iberia </td></tr><tr><td>London Luton </td><td>EasyJet </td></tr><tr><td>London Stansted </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr></table>'],
[36.675578,-4.494438,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Malaga airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">Belfast </td><td>Aer Lingus, EasyJet, Flybe, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Birmingham </td><td>bmibaby, Monarch, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Blackpool </td><td>Jet2 </td></tr><tr><td>Bournemouth </td><td>Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Bristol </td><td>EasyJet, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Cardiff </td><td>bmibaby, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Cork </td><td>Aer Lingus, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Doncaster Sheffield </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Dublin </td><td>Aer Lingus, Flybe, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>East Midlands </td><td>bmibaby, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Edinburgh </td><td>Flybe, Jet2, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Exeter </td><td>Flybe </td></tr><tr><td>Glasgow </td><td>EasyJet, Flybe, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Guernsey </td><td>Flybe </td></tr><tr><td>Jersey </td><td>Flybe </td></tr><tr><td>Leeds Bradford </td><td>Flybe, Jet2, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Liverpool </td><td>EasyJet, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>London Gatwick </td><td>airberlin, Aer Lingus, EasyJet, Monarch, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>London Heathrow </td><td>British Airways </td></tr><tr><td>London Luton </td><td>EasyJet, Monarch, </td></tr><tr><td>London Stansted </td><td>EasyJet, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Manchester </td><td>EasyJet, Flybe, Monarch, Jet2, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Newcastle </td><td>EasyJet, Flybe, Jet2, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Shannon </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Southampton </td><td>Flybe </td></tr></table>'],
[39.549059,2.731476,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Mallorca airport (Palma de Mallorca)</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="135">Aberdeen </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Belfast </td><td>EasyJet, Jet2, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Birmingham </td><td>bmibaby, Monarch, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Blackpool </td><td>Jet2 </td></tr><tr><td>Bournemouth </td><td>Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Bristol </td><td>EasyJet, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Cardiff </td><td>Bmibaby, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Cork </td><td>Aer Lingus, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Derry </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Dublin </td><td>Aer Lingus, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Doncaster Sheffield </td><td>EasyJet, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Durham Tees Valley </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>East Midlands </td><td>bmibaby, Jet2, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Edinburgh </td><td>EasyJet, Flybe, Jet2, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Exeter </td><td>Flybe, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Glasgow </td><td>EasyJet, Flybe, Jet2, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Guernsey </td><td>Flybe </td></tr><tr><td>Humberside </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Jersey </td><td>Flybe </td></tr><tr><td>Leeds Bradford </td><td>Flybe, Jet2, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Liverpool </td><td>EasyJet, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>London Gatwick </td><td>airberlin, EasyJet, Monarch, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>London Luton </td><td>EasyJet, Monarch, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>London Stansted </td><td>airberlin, EasyJet, Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Manchester </td><td>bmibaby, EasyJet, Flybe, Jet2, Monarch, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Newcastle </td><td>EasyJet, Flybe, Jet2, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Norwich </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Shannon </td><td>Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Southampton </td><td>Flybe, Thomson </td></tr></tr></table>'],
[39.864821,4.226303,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Menorca airport (Mahon)</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="135">Aberdeen </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Belfast </td><td>Jet2 </td></tr><tr><td>Birmingham </td><td>Monarch Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Bristol </td><td>EasyJet, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Cardiff </td><td>Bmibaby, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Doncaster Sheffield </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>East Midlands </td><td>bmibaby, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Edinburgh </td><td>Jet2 </td></tr><tr><td>Exeter </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Glasgow </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Leeds Bradford </td><td>Jet2 </td></tr><tr><td>Liverpool </td><td>EasyJet </td></tr><tr><td>London Gatwick </td><td>EasyJet, Monarch, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>London Luton </td><td>EasyJet, Monarch, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>London Stansted </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Manchester </td><td>EasyJet, Monarch, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Newcastle </td><td>EasyJet, Jet2, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Norwich </td><td>Thomson </td></tr></table>'],
[37.775192,-0.817623,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Murcia airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">Belfast </td><td>Jet2 </td></tr><tr><td>Birmingham </td><td>bmibaby, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Blackpool </td><td>Jet2 </td></tr><tr><td>Bournemouth </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Bristol </td><td>EasyJet </td></tr><tr><td>Cardiff </td><td>bmibaby </td></tr><tr><td>Dublin </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>East Midlands </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Edinburgh </td><td>Jet2 </td></tr><tr><td>Glasgow </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Leeds Bradford </td><td>Jet2, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Liverpool </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>London Gatwick </td><td>EasyJet </td></tr><tr><td>London Luton </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>London Stansted </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Manchester </td><td>Jet2 </td></tr><tr><td>Newcastle </td><td>EasyJet, Jet2 </td></tr></table>'],
[41.147509,1.156311,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Reus airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">Belfast </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Birmingham </td><td>Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Bristol </td><td>Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Cardiff </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Cork </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Derry </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Doncaster Sheffield </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Dublin </td><td>Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>East Midlands </td><td>Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Glasgow </td><td>Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Liverpool </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>London Gatwick </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>London Luton </td><td>Ryanair, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>London Stansted </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Manchester </td><td>Jet2, Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Newcastle </td><td>Thomson </td></tr><tr><td>Shannon </td><td>Thomson </td></tr></table>'],
[43.423315,-3.824015,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Santander airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">Dublin</td><td>Ryanair</td></tr><tr><td>London Stansted</td><td>Ryanair</td></tr></table>'],
[42.898604,-8.420506,'<b><u>Santiago de Compostela airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">Dublin</td><td>Aer Lingus</td></tr><tr><td>London Stansted</td><td>Ryanair</td></tr></table>'],
[37.423139,-5.899572,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Seville airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">Bristol </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Dublin </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Liverpool </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>London Gatwick </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>London Stansted </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>London Heathrow </td><td>Vueling </td></tr></table>'],
[39.492119,-0.476704,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Valencia airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">Bristol </td><td>EasyJet, Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>Dublin </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>East Midlands </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr><tr><td>London Gatwick </td><td>EasyJet </td></tr><tr><td>London Stansted </td><td>Ryanair </td></tr></table>'],
[41.70701,-4.846344,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Valladolid airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">Stansted</td><td>Ryanair</td></tr></table>'],
[42.883134,-2.730618,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Vitoria airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td>No flights from UK or Ireland at the moment</td></tr></table>'],
[41.663359,-1.008167,'<b><u>Flights Guide - Zaragoza airport</u></b><br><table class="verdana"><tr><td width="130">Stansted</td><td>Ryanair</td></tr></table>']
// End of common section
];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
var airimage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
  '../images/air_icon.png',
      new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(16, 35));

var airshadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
  '../images/hotel_shadow.png',
      new google.maps.Size(51, 37),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(16, 35));

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var airport = locations[i];
    var infocontent = airport [2]
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(airport[0], airport[1]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: airimage,
        shadow: airshadow
    });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        var ib = new InfoBox(ibOptions);
        boxText.innerHTML = infocontent;
        ib.open(map, marker);
        });
}
}

//]]>
</script> 
</head> 

<body onload="initialize()"> 
<div id="content">
<h1>Location - <?php echo $hotel; ?></h1>
<span class="verdana"><br /></span>
<table border=1 bordercolor="#666666">
      <tr>
        <td>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 640px; height: 450px"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
<br />
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

There are various trivia still to be sorted out, like the formatting of the infobox options but first I need to get the thing working. I suspect the problem lies in the "addListener" near the end of the script, but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ciao!*

@Chang has the right idea, but the closure should of course include the `airport` definition where there's an `[i]`

```
  var ib = new InfoBox(ibOptions);

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
    var airport = locations[i];
    var infocontent = airport [2]
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(airport[0], airport[1]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: airimage,
        shadow: airshadow
    });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        boxText.innerHTML = infocontent;
        ib.close();
        ib.open(map, marker);
        });
    })(i); 
  }
```

As I was testing I noticed the InfoBoxes become huge. The two ideas I present to you are:

1. Change `boxStyle`: Easy, but ugly because the scrollbar does not line up with the box, in my browser Chrome.

   ```
          var ibOptions = {
            content: boxText
           ,disableAutoPan: false
           ,maxWidth: 0
           ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(10, -50)
           ,zIndex: null
           ,boxStyle: { 
             width: "180px", // widened because of the scrollbar
             height: "150px",
             overflow: "auto"
            }
   ```
2. Change the style of your tables. In your case you call table styles "verdana". Less ugly, but needs work so it's not so much in the way..

   .verdana { display: block; max-height: 150px; overflow-y: auto; }

*Ciao!*

Comment: Solved, with the kind assistance of Mia. Thanks a lot. The styling of the box was never really a problem: I just did't intend to do that until I had something that worked. It's all done now.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've made some progress. I found out before that one div is enough for InfoBox, so I'm defining it outside the loop. Then, you need a closure for the `innerHTML` to persist. I noticed the content is static

```
  var infocontent = airport [2]
```

so I added `infocontent + i` inside the loop.

```
  var ib = new InfoBox(ibOptions);

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var airport = locations[i];
    var infocontent = airport [2]
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(airport[0], airport[1]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: airimage,
        shadow: airshadow
    });

    (function(i) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        boxText.innerHTML = infocontent + i;
        ib.open(map, this);
        });
    })(i);
```

Comment: Getting there!

It doesn't seem to matter where ib is defined, inside or outside the loop.

Changing ib.open(map, marker) to ib.open(map, this) has stopped the map jumping to a different location, but it still displays information for that location.

Addin "+i" to the innerHTML includes a number in the InfoBox which appears to be the position of the airport in the main array.

There's a definite pointer, so I hope I may make some more progress on my own accord now.